# Zurb Foundation 5 Reveal modal incorrectly positioned in IE11 only

Tags: css, internet-explorer, zurb-foundation

I am using the reveal modal from Foundation 5.

```
<div class="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>
    <h1>Awesome. I Have It.</h1>
    <p class="lead">Your couch. It is mine.</p>
    <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
    <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
```

This is working in FF, Chrome and Safari. However on IE11 the actual modal is pushed all the way to the bottom of the page outside of the currently visible viewport? Is there a change I need to make for IE11 to work properly?

Edit: This only happens on the first click. On the first open of the modal in IE11 the modal is rendered outside of the visible viewport, on a subsequent opens the modal is positioned correctly as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this has been reported as [an issue on Foundation's GitHub](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/3553). A fix hasn't been implemented yet, but that would be the place to check.